# Separate HTTP GET response from incoming file

Tags: c, http, sockets, get, response

I am working on a C program that uses sockets to retrieve a file using the HTTP GET request. I use the `recv` function to write to a buffer, then append a new file with the contents of the buffer. The program works fine except for one problem: The top of every file includes the HTTP response.

For example, I can successfully download and open a PDF file from the web using my program and it will open with no issues. However if I edit the PDF in Notepad++, I see the following at the top:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2012 19:57:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 PHP/5.3.8
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 21:31:31 GMT
ETag: "f2ae8c-4134aa-4c63b04c07df2"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4273322
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
%äðíø
10 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 2722>>
...
```

If I download the PDF file using my browser, the files match except for the HTML response at the top of the file retrieved by my program. I have verified this by removing the offending lines and comparing the file hashes.

I feel that there are much more elegant and proper ways of approaching this. I know that there are always two newline characters after the HTTP  response before the file begins, so here is my (sloppy, non-working) attempt at extracting the response:

```
FILE* ptr_file = fopen("PDF_TEST.pdf", "w+");
char* buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int file_pos   = 0;
int bytes_rcvd = 0;
int first_iter = 1;

while((bytes_rcvd = recv(socket_server, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0)
{
    if(first_iter)
    {// Need to remove the HTTP response from the buffer
        char* str_buffer;
        char* html_resp = strstr(buffer, "\n\n");
        int   html_resp_length = strlen(html_resp) + 2;
        printf("HTML RESPONSE:\n%s\n\n", html_resp);
        char* first_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE - html_resp_length];
        memcpy(first_buffer, buffer+html_resp_length-1, sizeof(first_buffer));
        printf("\n\nREST OF BUFFER:%s\n", first_buffer);
        bytes_rcvd -= html_resp_length;
        fwrite(first_buffer, 1, bytes_rcvd, ptr_file);
        first_iter = 0;
        continue;
    }           
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_rcvd, ptr_file); 
    file_pos += bytes_rcvd;
}
```

I get segmentation faults with this code, but I believe that's due to the fact that my buffer is an array of `char*` and I'm using it as if it where a `char` array.

My questions:
1.) What is the best way of separating the HTTP response from the file?
2.) Is it better to use the `Content-Length` specified by the HTML response for writing to the file, or should I use my current method of writing the number of bytes received?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: HTTP uses CRLF (i.e. `'\r\n'` or `0x0D 0x0A`) for line endings, not plain LF (`'\n'`).  Also, don't confuse HTML (the markup language) with HTTP (the protocol).

Comment: You're mistaking HTML headers with HTTP headers. What you're seeing here is HTTP.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, not sure why I was saying HTML. I have corrected the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to have two loops: The first for the response header, read until you get an empty line. The second receive loop for the data.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're running into trouble with your `str*` function calls because you're assuming the buffer is null-terminated.  You could receive `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` bytes and then set `buffer[bytes_recvd] = '\0'` before doing your tests.

Also, as others have pointed out, you need to look for `"\r\n\r\n"` instead of `"\n\n"` as the termination of your headers.

Be careful to handle the condition where the CR LF CR LF sequence crosses two different recv() calls.  One possible workaround to this possibility would be to copy the last three bytes of `buffer` to the start of `buffer`, and have your next read begin at `&buffer[3]`.